# Dart JSONP callback error

Tags: javascript, callback, dart

I am currently trying to receive data using JSONP. When I hit 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&callback=callbackForJsonpApi

I get the response perfectly fine:

`callbackForJsonpApi({RESPONSE HERE})`

But when I go to https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEYHERE/37.8267,-122.423?callback=callbackforJsonApi I get:

```
typeof callbackforJsonApi === 'function' && callbackforJsonApi({ RESPONSE HERE})
```

Can anyone explain why I have that "typeof" part prepended to one response but not the other?

This is my site.dart file:

```
void main() {

  // listen for the postMessage from the main page
  window.onMessage.listen(dataReceived);
  ScriptElement script = new Element.tag("script");
  script.src = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/37.8267,-122.423?callback=callbackforJsonApi";
  document.body.children.add(script);
}

dataReceived(MessageEvent dataReceived) {
  var data = JSON.parse(dataReceived.data);
  print(data['responseData']);
}
```

This is my partial html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function callbackForJsonpApi(s) {
            var data = JSON.stringify(s);
            window.postMessage(data, '*');
          }
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you are getting different responses from different servers, so isn't it just a matter of the servers being configured differently?

Comment: That it, it doesn't sound like the problem is JavaScript or Dart related, but rather is purely on the servers. The latter seems to be guarding the call to avoid an error if the `callbackforJsonApi` function isn't defined - then it just does nothing instead of throwing an exception. That's "non-standard" (not that there is a standard for JSONP, but it's not traditional), but if interpreted as JavaScript, it should be safe.

Comment: So on my end I can only ask them to change how they handle that?

Comment: Basically, yes, if you need them to change the format. I don't know how you are fetching or using the responses. If the response is run as JavaScript, it should be fine anyway. It can't be run as plain Dart code with either format (top-level function calls are not valid Dart). If you receive the text as a string and then use it later, you can cut off the first part of the string before using it. It all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added in a sample of my code. I was trying to do the hacky solution and basically cut out everything up to the &&. I just was not sure at what point I can do that...Got any insight?

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why these are different; seems like a bit of an oversight on Google's part (presumably they should be the same).

Both of them are valid; but the one with the extra check looks best; it's only trying to call the function if it exists (and is a function); which will stop a JavaScript error if you haven't declared the function.

If you're pulling this in server-side and spitting the code into your page; you should probably try and make your code tolerate both of these; just in case you happen to get different behaviour in the future (eg. if Google make these consistent).